# how to factor $x-7\sqrt{x}-18$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I want to factor $$x-7\sqrt{x}-18$$
I've trid $$(x-7\sqrt{x}-18)^2$$ But then $$x^2-49x-324$$Cannot be factored.
May I know how to factor this? thanks!

Comment: Why are you squaring?  And $(x-7\sqrt x -18)^2 \ne x^2 - 49x -324$.

Comment: And whatever $(x- 7\sqrt x - 18)^2$ *does* equal, it can be factored as $(x- 7\sqrt x - 18)(x- 7\sqrt x - 18)$.

Comment: $(a - b - c)^2 \ne a^2 - b^2 - c^2$.

Comment: I originally wanted to cancel the square root so I did the squaring, I think I missed the square root for x2−49x−324, anyway, now I just discovered a new technique to do this kind of factoring, thank you very much

Comment: To cancel cancel the square root *AND* to find a value for $x$ where $x-7\sqrt x - 18=0$ you must isolate the square root $7\sqrt x = {x-18}$ then square $49x = x^2 -36x+324$ so $x^2 - 85x + 324 = 0$ and that factors to $(x-81)(x-4)=0$ but $x=18+7\sqrt x > 18$ so $x = 81$ and $\sqrt x = 9$.  This is compatible with replacing $\sqrt x$ with $y$ and factoring $y^2 - 7y-18=(y+2)(y-9)$ so $y=-2$ or $y=9$ but as $y =\sqrt x \ge 0$ we must have $y = \sqrt x = 9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y= \sqrt{x}$. Then your expression is $y^2-7y-18$. But this factors as $(y+2)(y-9)$ so that factored your expression is $(\sqrt{x}+2)(\sqrt{x}-9)$.

Comment: Missed a stray 0 in your edit.

Comment: @Mike Thank you! I caught one but the other was missed. With my shift key going, ')'s are quickly turning into 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sqrt x$ so $x -7\sqrt x -18 = y^2 -7y -18$ which by quadratic formula has roots

$ \frac{7 \pm \sqrt{49+ 4*18}} 2= \frac {7\pm \sqrt{121}}2=\frac {7+11}2, \frac {7-11}2 = 9,-2$

So $y^2 - 7y -18 = (y-9)(y+2)$

And $x-7\sqrt{x } - 18= (\sqrt x-9)(\sqrt x+2)$